# how can I deploy laravel with vite on the shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, vite, shared-hosting

I work with Laravel 10 which uses vite and when I uploaded the project on the shared hosting it shows me an error -> Vite manifest not found at: /home/exampleuser/example/public/build/manifest.json

how can I solve it?
I can't use a terminal on the hosting.

I try npm run build locally and uploaded again but it still returned this error.
also, I try PHP artisan optimize:clear but it doesn't work

Comment: When it is time to deploy your app for production, simply run the `vite build` command.  [1](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build)

Comment: Did you check whether the expected file exists at the given location?

Comment: Yes I checked and exists this file. I run npm run build locally and when it is built then upload files again on the server, next I check public/build/manifest.json and it exists but doesn't work